# Is my CNN Model working fine or have any problem?

Tags: tensorflow

My model shows validation loss decreases, then increases, and then decreases again??? Is my model working fine or have any type of problem like overfitting etc.?

[Training and Validation Loss Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCdu8.png)

[Training and Validation Accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB85R.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so what you are describing seems to be an overfitting problem.

Some of the possible reasons are

1. Your data is very noisy
2. Your data is very small
3. You created a very complex model, adding unnecessary layers
4. Your learning rate is too high

These are some of the common reasons for an overfitting model.